# Ending pthreads with deferred cancelation

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, signals, mutex

I'm new to pthreads and signal handling and I am working on a project that will create `x` amount of pthreads as either a producer or consumer, that execute forever, and I want to end all threads and then the main in a systematic way.

To do this, I am attempting to catch the `^c` with a signal handler and then setting some global flag to then end the threads.

I have tried doing the following but I am unsure if it is working or not and I would like advice on my thought process and implementation.

Here is what I am working with, omitting error checking:

```
#include stdio, pthread, stdlib, semaphore, time, string, unistd, signal

sem_t empty, full;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int flag = 0;
void *producer();
void *consumer();
void sig_handler(int sig);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   signal(handler(SIGINT, sig_handler);

   //init locks and semas
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
   sem_init(&empty, 0, SOME_BUFFER_SIZE);
   sem_init(&full, 0, 0);

   pthread_t prod_threads[5]; //5 for example, can be any amount passed in
   pthread_t cons_threads[3];

   //start up threads
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      pthread_create(&prod_threads[i], NULL, producer, NULL)
   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      pthread_create(&cons_threads[i], NULL, consumer, NULL)

   //join threads at end
   for(i = 0; i < PROD; i++)
     pthread_join(&prod_threads[i], NULL);

   for(i = 0; i < CONS; i++)
     pthread_join(&cons_threads[i], NULL);

   sleep(4);//could be any amount of time
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
//not sure if I am going about this the right way
void sig_handler(int sig){
  if(sig == SIGINT)
    flag = 1;

}

void *producer(){
  while(1){
    sleep(x);//where x is some random time

    //part I am concerned about:
     if(flag)
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    //get locks and semaphore stuff
    //enter crit section
    //release locks, semaphore
  }
 void *consumer(){
   while(1){
      sleep(x);//sleep some random time

      //again not sure if this is right or not
      if(flag)
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      //get locks
      //enter crit
      //release locks
  }



 }
}
```

My program seems to execute properly, I'm just not sure if I am using pthreads and signals correctly and would like some guidance there. If you need more complete code just let me know

Thanks

Comment: 'I want to end both threads and then the main in a systematic way' want.. or need?

Comment: @MartinJames to be honest I'm not sure why I want to yet, but I would like to end the threads first

Comment: Even if you have an actual need, it's usual to end consumers by queueing them a message that tells them to terminate themselves.  I usually queue up a NULL, and any consumer that gets a NULL queues it back up and terminates.  That kills off all the consumers, no matter how many, with no need to for the last consumer to free the 'poison pill' termination message.  No sleep(), no waiting:)

Comment: oh. I think that what I'm tying to do then. I want to send a signal to my threads and tell them to kill themselves. to kill themselves I say use `exit()` but idk if that's the graceful way to do this

Comment: First of all forget 'graceful' unless there is an overriding need for it.  'works', (as in 'shuts down promptly when commanded), is better than a lot of commercial multithreaded apps offer.   You know the ones - you click on the cross icon and they go dead for 30 seconds?  Those are the ones programmed by the 'I must always shut down threads gracefully upon process termination' cabal:)  If you do use an explicit shutdown mechanism, pthread_exit() is fine.

Comment: :) thanks for the info! This is mostly just an exercise for me to acquainted with multithreaded techniques, but I do appreciate some real world advice as that `real world` implementations often get overlooked. using `pthread_exit()` instead of `exit()` seemed to actually kill those threads. But now my main program hangs after using `^c`

Comment: @panthor314 Hangs indefinitely, or longer than you think it should?

Comment: @yano it appears indefintely

Comment: Where did you define `PROD` and `CONS`? why not use them also in the `pthread_t` arrays?

Comment: @panthor314 Hmm,, could you post the code you're actually running?  What you've posted doesn't compile .. but once I worked around that it wasn't hanging indefinitely for me (although it does seem to take longer than I would expect to exit). And fyi, I think this is a good pthread tutorial: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Answer (score 0):

You're execution seems appropriate, however using the docs @yano provided, you're `pthread_join()` is off ever so slightly.

Instead of:

```
for(i = 0; i < PROD; i++)
 pthread_join(&prod_threads[i], NULL);

for(i = 0; i < CONS; i++)
 pthread_join(&cons_threads[i], NULL);
```

You need:

```
for(i = 0; i < PROD; i++)
 pthread_join(prod_threads[i], NULL);

for(i = 0; i < CONS; i++)
 pthread_join(cons_threads[i], NULL);
```

Notice the ampersand. Whether or not this is what you are looking for, I am not sure, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to end all threads and then the main in a systematic way.

As Martin James suggests, post a special thread message into the queue telling the worker threads to terminate. This message should not be removed from the queue, so that all worker threads have a chance to receive it and terminate.

The other point is that you should not call `exit` in your worker threads, since this function terminates the entire process, defeating your original goal. Just `return` from the thread function.

Another point is that in a multi-threaded application it is good practice to handle all signals in one specific thread (often the main thread is the best candidate for that). And block the signals you expect to receive in all other threads. It should be done by blocking the expected signals before creating other threads, so that they inherit the signal mask, and eventually unblocking these signals in the signal handling thread when it is ready to handle them (e.g. when all extra threads have been created). This is because a signal targeted for a process (such as `SIGINT`) can be delivered to any one of its threads, but we want it to be handled by one specific thread. See [Signal Generation and Delivery](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04) for more details.